# How to unpack abi.Arguments() and access values by name

Tags: go-ethereum, abi

I am trying to unpack encoded arguments in `input` field of trunsaction.
`Input` field consist of 2 params: `blockId` and `Input` (another input field) - and I got stuck unpacking this 2nd input.

```
var evidenceComponents = []abi.ArgumentMarshaling{
    {
        Name: "metaHash",
        Type: "bytes32",
    },
    {
        Name: "parentHash",
        Type: "bytes32",
    },
    {
        Name: "blockHash",
        Type: "bytes32",
    },
    {
        Name: "signalRoot",
        Type: "bytes32",
    },
    {
        Name: "graffiti",
        Type: "bytes32",
    },
    {
        Name: "prover",
        Type: "address",
    },
    {
        Name: "parentGasUsed",
        Type: "uint32",
    },
    {
        Name: "gasUsed",
        Type: "uint32",
    },
    {
        Name: "verifierId",
        Type: "uint16",
    },
    {
        Name: "proof",
        Type: "bytes",
    },
}

var EvidenceType, _ = abi.NewType("tuple", "BlockEvidence", evidenceComponents)
var EvidenceArgs = abi.Arguments{{Name: "Evidence", Type: EvidenceType}}

type a struct {
    MetaHash      [32]uint8 "json:\"metaHash\"";
    ParentHash    [32]uint8 "json:\"parentHash\"";
    BlockHash     [32]uint8 "json:\"blockHash\"";
    SignalRoot    [32]uint8 "json:\"signalRoot\"";
    Graffiti      [32]uint8 "json:\"graffiti\"";
    Prover        common.Address "json:\"prover\"";
    ParentGasUsed uint32 "json:\"parentGasUsed\"";
    GasUsed       uint32 "json:\"gasUsed\"";
    VerifierId    uint16 "json:\"verifierId\"";
    Proof         []uint8 "json:\"proof\""
}

encodedData := "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"

decodeData, err := hex.DecodeString(encodedData)

if method, ok := contractAbi.Methods["proveBlock"]; ok {
    params, err := method.Inputs.Unpack(decodeData[4:])
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    // params[1] contains Input data    
    i := params[1]
    b, _ := i.([]byte)

e, _ := EvidenceArgs.Unpack(b) // returns []interface{}

for _, x := range e {
l := x.(a).MetaHash
}
```

```
panic: interface conversion: interface {} is struct { MetaHash [32]uint8 "json:\"metaHash\""; ParentHash [32]uint8 "json:\"parentHash\""; BlockHash [32]uint8 "json:\"blockHash\""; SignalRoot [32]uint8 "json:\"signalRoot\""; Graffiti [32]uint8 "json:\"graffiti\""; Prover common.Address "json:\"prover\""; ParentGasUsed uint32 "json:\"parentGasUsed\""; GasUsed uint32 "json:\"gasUsed\""; VerifierId uint16 "json:\"verifierId\""; Proof []uint8 "json:\"proof\"" }, not main.a

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.main()
        /Users/d/tx_decode.go:118 +0x6d6
exit status 2
```